# PostGIS runs out of memory due to the use of spatial index

Tags: postgis, spatial-index

I am running this query on PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS (SELECT 
    t1.id
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        (SELECT 
            t2.geometry AS geom_closest
        FROM table2 t2
        ORDER BY t1.geometry <-> t2.geometry
        LIMIT 1) AS nn);
```

To explain it quickly: I have a grid of points in table1, a list of features in table2. I want to find, for each point in table1, the minimum closest feature in table2 (for example, say I have in table2 the roads in the state of NY, and in table1 a regular grid over the state of NY, then for each point in my grid I want to find the closest road).

I have 8GB of RAM on my server. My tables are pretty small all things considered.

```
 tablename                  |    indexname                   |  num_rows   | table_size | index_size | unique | number_of_scans | tuples_read | tuples_fetched 
table1                      | table1_idx                     | 1.47763e+06 | 96 MB      | 82 MB      | N      |               0 |           0 |              0
table1                      | table1_pkey                    | 1.47763e+06 | 96 MB      | 32 MB      | Y      |               0 |           0 |              0
table2                      | table2_pkey                    |        2916 | 8640 kB    | 80 kB      | Y      |               1 |        2916 |              0
```

Now, if I create a spatial index on table2 (GIST index), my system go crazy with my query. The RAM used takes off and eventually (< 5 minutes) my server runs out of memory and crashes hard:

```
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

If I do not use a spatial index, then my memory usage stays at 0.5% and my query just takes forever.

What is wrong with my query? How can I improve it? I will need to run the same kind of query on much larger datasets and I do not understand why using my spatial index breaks everything.

postgis_version: 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: I’m just learning this stuff myself, but do you have a reason to order and limit results when creating this table?

Comment: I want the closest feature, so by ordering and taking the first results, I get it the closest feature from my point easily

Comment: Maybe you could limit your search for the nearest point, like: don’t look past 200m. [This page could help](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html).

Comment: I could, but I need to know the distance for every point. Though an upper limit could help reduce calculations a little indeed, I'll give that a shot with a 50 miles or something.

Comment: look into clustering the index...i would also recreate the table and just add a fresh index...seems strange why this is a problem with your tables. I have run a similar cross join lateral query with around 1 million points to polygons with no problems on the indexes

Comment: After `vacuum analyze` on the two tables, you may want to review the Postgres configuration to ensure you are not allowing it to consume more memory than available.

Comment: @JGH do you know where that configuration would be? Wasn't able to find something obvious after a cursory search

Comment: I tried changing work_mem from the default 4MB to 1MB. This does not improve the situation unfortunately

Comment: @WilliamAbma read on PG tuning. All/most memory settings are interconnected and depends on the number of connections. Not having enough memory would mean a very slow processing. Misconfiguration would mean trying to consume more memory than available - and crash

Comment: @JGH Thanks, will definitely do that. The good thing is that I now understand why my query generates such a RAM-hungry process. I do not yet understand how to remediate it besides breaking the query into chunks which I'd like to avoid, but that's a start at least.